# How am I to download and extract the Stack Overflow Creative Commons data dump?

Tags: support, data-dump

I downloaded the 7z file but cannot unzip it with WinZip. What do I need for an old Windows98 PC?

Answer (score 4):

You need [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), which is compatible with Windows 98.

Answer (score 3):

You need a new PC.  Windows 98 is no longer supported, even by microsoft, to the extent that new security patches are no longer released.  It is unsafe to use Windows 98 on any computer connected to the internet.

Additionally, you will need a database engine.  The dump is not a ready-made program that you can write queries for, but raw xml data that must be loaded into a database engine.  It's worth noting here that the database engined used by the StackOverflow team (Sql Server) will also not install on Windows 98.  You can, of course, use a different less discriminating database if you choose to.

Once your are sure of those things, take a look at 7zip, as that is the format used to zip the file.